# how to solve this error Target host must not be null, or set in parameters in this code

Tags: java, android, web-services, http, bitmap

> I am try to downloading the image from url in a listview but this code
>   give the error "**Target host must not be null, or set in parameters**" and how to remove this error

```
public Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: post your url string

Comment: cdn.travelpartnerweb.com/DesiyaImages/Image/1/nxd/maw/qyj/ibt/HO_TN.jpg

Comment: Try this url :`http://cdn.travelpartnerweb.com/DesiyaImages/Image/1/nxd/maw/qyj/ibt/HO_TN.jpg`

Comment: i can already use that

Comment: Have you set  `internet Permission` in manifest ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Try to use other `url` and if it works that means problem is in your `url` posted above